# Authlogic session in Capybara doesn't exist immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara, authlogic

My spec:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

 context 'When user is logged in' do
    scenario 'Log in' do
      visit login_path

      within '.new_user_session' do
        fill_in 'username', with: user.email
        fill_in 'password', with: user.password
        click_on 'Log in'
      end

      visit new_search_path

      expect(page).to have_text "Welcome #{user.name}!"
    end
  end
```

The issue is that when visiting `new_search_path`, even though the login in successful, the page behaves as if there is no user logged in. If I add a `sleep(1)` call right before `visit new_search_path`, everything works fine.

Anyone know why this is happening?

I'm using authlogic, capybara, and selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action triggered.by `click_on` can occur asynchronously.  Therefore, if you do a `visit` immediately after it can cause the login request to abort and the session cookies never get set. To solve that you need to check for page text/content that indicates the login has succeeded. Something like

```
expect(page).to have_text 'You are now logged in'
```